# How to change text colour in a ListView

Tags: android, listview, colors, custom-lists

I'm working on my first Android app and after going through many of the answers already posted here, they have refined my understanding but can't seem to solve my problem.

Simply put, I have a `ListView` and I want the text in certain rows to be different from others. I am trying to do this by casting the `ListView.GetItemAtPosition` to a `TextView` and changing the text color of that, but I am getting a casting exception.

Either helping me figure the error in my code or suggesting a better way would be much appreciated!

```
public class MeetingManager extends Activity {

public ListView mAgenda;

//public Item agenda = new Item();
List<Item> agenda=new ArrayList<Item>();
ArrayAdapter<Item> adapter=null;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.v(TAG, "Activity State: onCreate()");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.meeting);

    // Obtain handles to UI objects
    mAgenda = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstAgenda);

    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<Item>(this, R.layout.agendalist, agenda);
    mAgenda.setAdapter(adapter);        
    mAgenda.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

    //Load items into agenda
    initAgenda();
}

protected void updateDetails() {
    mRecipients.setText("This message will be sent to items " + (currentItemNum + 1) + " and later:");
    mSMS.setText(currentItem.getSMS());
}

protected void initAgenda() {
    currentItem = new Item();
    currentItem.setTitle("Reset Meeting");
    adapter.add(currentItem);
    setColour(0, Color.RED);
}

public void setColour(int pos, int col) {
    TextView tv = (TextView)mAgenda.getItemAtPosition(pos); //This is where the exception is thrown
    tv.setTextColor(col);
}
}
```

---

The following is my XML code for the `ListView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@android:id/text1"  
    android:paddingTop="2dip" 
    android:paddingBottom="3dip"
    android:textSize="12pt" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a custom adapter and use `TextView.setTextColor();` in the `getView` method depending upon your criteria for coloration.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = View.inflate(context, layout, null);
    View row = convertView;

    TextView first = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ListItem1);
    TextView second = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ListItem2);
    if(condition == changecolor) {
        first.setTextColor(#FFFF0000);
        second.setTextColor(#FFFF0000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can subclass `ArrayAdapter` and inside your subclass' getView method, you can perform the magic

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  TextView tv = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

  if (position < 3) {     // I have just put dummy condition you can put your condition
    textView.setTextColor(colors);  // Here you can put your color
  } else {
    textView.setTextColor(colors);
  }
}
```